# Kubernetes top vs Linux top

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Kubernetes top (kubectl top) command shows different memory usage than Linux top command ran inside pod.

I’ve created k8s deployment where YAML contains these memory limits:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: "1"
    memory: 2500Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 200m
    memory: 2Gi
```

Following commands have output as shown:

```
bash4.4$ kubectl top pod PODNAME 

NAME                     CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
openam-d975d46ff-rnp6h   2m           1205Mi
```

Run linux top command:

```
Kubectl exec -it PODNAME top 

Mem: 12507456K used, 4377612K free, 157524K shrd, 
187812K buff, 3487744K cached
```

Note ‘free -g’ also shows 11Gb used.

Issue is this contradicts "kubectl top" which shows only 1205 mb used.

Comment: This question seems like it belongs to https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Command `kubectl top` shows metrics for a given pod. That information is based on reports from [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor), which collects real pods resource usage.

If you run `top` inside the pod, it will be like you run it on the host system because the pod is using kernel of the host system.
Unix `top` uses `proc` virtual filesystem and reads `/proc/meminfo`file to get an actual information about current memory status. Containers inside pods partially share `/proc`with the host system include path about a memory and CPU information.

More information you can find in these documents: [kubectl-top-pod man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/kubectl-top-pod), [Memory inside Linux containers](https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/)