# How to get iostats of a container running in a pod on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Memory and cpu resources of a container can be tracked using prometheus. But can we track I/O of a container? Are there any metrices available?

Comment: may be `docker stats --no-stream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Docker containers you can check the data with the `docker stats` command (as [P...](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309601/p) mentioned in the comment). [Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/#extended-description) you can find more information about this command.

> If you want to check pods cpu/memory usage without installing any third party tool then you can get memory and cpu usage of pod from cgroup.
>
> 1. Go to pod's exec mode  `kubectl exec pod_name -- /bin/bash`
> 2. Go to  `cd /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu`  for cpu usage run  `cat cpuacct.usage`
> 3. Go to  `cd /sys/fs/cgroup/memory`  for memory usage run  `cat memory.usage_in_bytes`

For more look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531646/checking-kubernetes-pod-cpu-and-memory).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641310/kubernetes-top-vs-linux-top/51656039#51656039) you can find another interesting question. You should know, that

> Containers inside pods partially share `/proc`with the host system include path about a memory and CPU information.

See also this article about [Memory inside Linux containers](https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/).